# Job search 'Create alert' button is where the search button should be

Tags: discussion, user-interface

When using the job search I type in the field then click the 'Create alert' button, thinking it is the search button. It's in the same place that the search button should be, it's the same colour and I accidentally click it every single time.

Can this button be moved, and replaced with an actual search button?

I've added screenshots to show how similar it is to the other search buttons on the site.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**EDIT:**
I have also just noticed that the company search has the same layout and a search button, making the create alert button even more out of place:

[image]

**UPDATE:**
This button has now been changed to "Save Search" and looks even more like the search buttons everywhere else!
[image]

Comment: Wait, you actually click the search button and don't press enter? I find that odd, but I do agree with you, there should be a search button attached/beside the search criteria (to the right of "Located anywhere"). Just looked and there is a search button if you expand the search filters.

Comment: Yeah I always seem to end up clicking it, even though I press enter on all the boxes that actually have a search button. I think it's because there's more than one entry field, it feels more like a form.

Comment: People using mobile devices use the enter button with less frequency. They will look for a search icon to touch.